# Why is the normal vector to the surface $f$ given by $\text{grad}(f)$?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

According to my lecture notes, the normal vector to a surface $f$ is given by $\text{grad}(f) = \underline{\nabla} f$. However, surely the normal vector to the surface $f$ should be perpendicular to the vector $\underline{\nabla}f$?

Comment: Duplicate of [Find normal vector for the surface F(x,y)=0](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/754433/856) and [Why is the gradient of implicit surface the normal vector (i.e. parallel to the normal line)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1451237/856)

Answer (score 0):

If the surface, $M$, say, is given by $f^{-1}(c)$ for a regular value $c$ of $f$ then $f$ is constant along $M$. So for any curve $\gamma(t)$ in $M$, $f\circ \gamma= c$ and consequently
$$\frac{d}{dt}f\circ \gamma = 0 =\langle \gamma^\prime, (\nabla f)\circ\gamma\rangle$$
Since any tangent vector to $M$ arises as a tangent to a curve in $M$, $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to $M$.

Comment: What are the domains and codomains of $\gamma$ and $f$ you had in mind here?

Comment: @EliRose It does not really matter, but the standard case is, for sure, that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma:(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon ) \rightarrow M := f^{-1}(c)$